# make array to be divisble by 3

Tags: c, arrays

i need to write an function that gets to arrays and merge between them into new array.
if the size of the new array is not divisible by 3 without remainder i need to increase to the first bigger number that divisible by 3 without remainder

big is 10
and small is 5
but if big is 11
and small is 5
i need to increase the size of the array to 18
i need to write to any number that big and small can be

```
void fromArrayToMatrix(int arr1[],int sz,int arr2[],int s2){
      int i,j,k;
      int row,cul,size,sum;
      int arr_temp[big_size+small_size];
      for (i=0;i<sz;i++)    
          arr_temp[i]=arr1[i];
      fo(k=0;k<s2;k++)
          arr_temp[k+sz]=arr2[k];
}
```

Comment: What's the problem that you're running into?

Answer (score 0):

- create dynamic array: use malloc
- calculate size: `ceil(16/3)*3 = 18`

Answer (score 0):

If you allocate memory statically then the logic will become complicated.So allocate memory dynamically and save memory too.